# Ошибка при указании platformVersion для ndk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.snostorm.rakdroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName "raknet"
            cFlags "-DANDROID_NDK"
            stl "stlport_shared"
            platformVersion = "15"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Вот содержание моего app build.gradle. При попытке собрать проект получаю ошибку:

```
No such property: platformVersion for class:
com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions_Decorated
```

В чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать экспериментальную версию gradle. Как подключить описано [тут](http://www.mzan.com/article/37742770-androidstudio-cant-find-opencv-headers.shtml) во втором посте.